# Printing Array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I have included my screenshot when running my code and you can look at the end of my original array and sorted array.
After I print the original array and the sorted array I always get some sign at the end of the array. How could I fix that?

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include <algorithm>
    using namespace std;

    //Sort Function:
    void Sorted_Array(char fullarray[20])
    {
    int i, j, temp;
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        for (j = i + 1; j < 20; j++) {
            if (fullarray[i] > fullarray[j]) {
                temp = fullarray[i];
                fullarray[i] = fullarray[j];
                fullarray[j] = temp;
            }
        }
        
    }
    cout << "Sorted Array is: " << fullarray<<endl;
    }
    

    //Frequent Function:
    void freq(char array[20])
    {
    int count[20],max,letter;
    max = 1; letter=0;
    
        for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
        count[i] = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (array[i] == array[j]) {
                count[i]++;
            }
            if (count[i] > max) {       
                max = count[i];
                letter = i;
            }
        }               
        }
        if (max == 19) {
        cout << "All character entered are the same"<<endl;
     }
    else if (max == 1) {
        cout << "All character entered are different"<<endl;
    }
    else
        cout << "\n" "The most frequent letter is: " << array[letter] << " and Number of time it was entered is: " << max << endl;
    }



    int main() {
    char arr[20];
    cout << "Enter 20 alphabet: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) 
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
            if (!isalpha(arr[i]))
                cout << arr[i] << " is not an alphabet" << endl;
                for (int j = 0; j < i; j++){
                    if (arr[i] == arr[j]){
                        cout << arr[i] << " is a duplicate letter." << endl;
                    }
                }       
    }
    system("cls");
    cout << "Array is: " << arr << endl;
    Sorted_Array(arr);
    freq(arr);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
    }
```

Here is my screenshot after running the code
[image]

I should get only the array not those sign at the end.

Answer (score 0):

When you print character array, you need null character('\0') at the end to terminate. Otherwise, program won't know when to end and keep printing until it finds 0.

```c
int main() {
    char arr[21];
    arr[20] = 0;
    ...
}
```

Add a single null character at the end of the array and it will work.